# API versioning with fall-through in Spring 3.2 MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm porting an existing web service to Spring 3.2. I need versioned APIs and have a controller for every new version. I do not want to re-defined methods in newer Controllers and instead want to automatically map requests to old controller if it's not found in the latest.

For example, if `ControllerV1` has `/home` and `/login` and `ControllerV2` has `/login`, then I want requests to be routed like this.

```
/home -> ControllerV1
/v1/home -> ControllerV1
/v2/home -> ControllerV1

/login -> ControllerV1
/v1/login -> ControllerV1
/v2/login -> ControllerV2
```

One option would be to provide multiple paths in `@RequestMapping`. However, that would mean removing paths from all older controllesr whenever adding the API in a newer version. What is the most elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to simply use inheritance for that:

**Version1Controller.java**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("v1/")
public class Version1Controller {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("foo")
    public String foo() {
        return "Foo 1";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("bar")
    public String bar() {
        return "bar 1";
    }
}
```

**Version2Controller.java**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "v2/", "latest/" })
public class Version2Controller extends Version1Controller {

    @Override
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("bar")
    public String bar() {
        return "bar 2";
    }

}
```

Here you will have following urls mapped:

- `v1/foo` - returning "Foo 1"
- `v2/foo` - returning "Foo 1" - inherited from Version 1
- `v1/bar` - returning "Bar 1"
- `v2/bar` - returning "Bar 2" - overriding behavior from Version 1.
- `latest/foo` - same as `v2/foo`
- `latest/bar` - same as `v2/bar`

Comment: What if the signature changes? Exemple : public String bar() will become public Integer bar()